# PHP / SVGgraph data amount labels

Tags: php, svggraph

Using SVGgraph, is it possible to show only the 'data amount' label but not the label of the data ("l1", "l2" and "l3" in the example)?
My code looks like this:

```
require_once("svggraph/SVGGraph.php");
$data = array("l1" => 45, "l2" => 20, "l3" => 35);
$settings = array('show_data_labels' => true, 'show_label_amount' => true);
$graph = new SVGGraph(300, 200, $settings);
$graph->colours = $cols;
$graph->Values($data);
$graph->Fetch('SemiDonutGraph');
```

But when I use show_data_labels = true then it's displayed both the value and the labels "l1", "l2" and "l3". If I set it to false then nothing is shown. Is there a way to show only the value amount?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done this way:

```
array([option => value, option2 => value2]); 

$settings = array(['show_data_labels' => true, 'show_label_amount' => true]);
```

Comment: True. I modified the question. That does not solve the problem, though.